# Sequence of model creation in Django

Tags: database, django, django-syncdb

I have created a permission system in django. It is inside an App called `HelperApp`. First it inputs permissions definition into the database with `post_syncdb` signals(sender is the `models` of HelperApp, which does not contain any model classes), and then listens to the `post_save` of `User` in `django.contrib.auth`, and add default permissions to them.

Now the problem is, when there was no database file yet and I call `manage.py syncdb`, the Auth App will create some default users right after the `User` table is created (Superuser and AnonymousUser). The permission system tries to give them default permissions, but the permissions are not created yet.

Currently, only if I put 'HelperApp' **before** 'django.contrib.auth' in `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` will it work. The question is, is there a way to define the sequence of table creation without the need of juggling names in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: `syncdb` doesn't create any users you don't tell it to. It will ask you if you want to setup a superuser, but you can always decline. `AnonymousUser` is a primitive; it's not actually stored in the database. It's just the "default" user before login, so `request.user` is always *something*.

Comment: I believe AnonymousUser is a record, I can see it from 'User.objects.all()' and it do triggers 'post_save' signal during syncdb process

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be. If you have an actual "AnonymousUser" in your database, then you've got bigger problems than this issue. Do you have any `init_data.json` fixtures lying around anywhere? Because that's coming from something other than `syncdb`.

Comment: No, I don't have fixtures at the moment. This AnonymousUser entry has an id of -1 and can be seen in various ways (sqlite browser as well). I'm using django 1.3

Comment: OK, never mind, it comes from an App called "django-guardian". Is it a big problem? Then I should probably discard this App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use fixtures to create your inital data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Comment: Hi Marcin! Thanks for the information about fixtures. Is it bad to use post_syncdb to pre-populate database?